# how to create multiple sheet in a single workbook in selenium ..and extract data for each sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

i want to create multiple sheet in single workbook.how to write the code in selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String[]> value=null;
        Set<String> uniquename = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String[]> data1 = new  ArrayList<String[]>();
        data1.add( new String[] {"Apple iPhone 8 Plus (Space Grey, 64 GB)","56000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone 6 (Grey, 128 GB)","47000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)","28000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)","29000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Gold, 128 GB)","19000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Gold, 128 GB)","18000"});

        Map<String,List<String[]> > hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String,List<String[]> >();

        for(String[] data:data1) {
public static  void write(String name, String pname, String pprice) {

         XSSFSheet sheet = workbook1.createSheet(name);
         Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
         Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
         Cell cell2 = row.createCell(1);

         cell1.setCellValue(pname);
         cell2.setCellValue(pprice);

    }


    public static void save(XSSFWorkbook workbook)
    {
        try
        {

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("iphonedata_demo.xlsx");
            workbook.write(out);

            out.close();
            System.out.println("iphonedata_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
        }catch (Exception e) {

        } 
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you please describe what isn't working or what **exactly** prevents you from creating the desired workbook?

Comment: actually i want to store all apple iphone 8plus phone name and price in one sheet.then all apple iphone xs in another sheet like this.i dont know how to create different excel sheet and store their value .....plz help me....

Comment: This is nothing to do with Selenium, it looks like a Apache POI question

Comment: yes it is apache poi...but i cant understand how to write code...plz help me

Comment: You should really think about creating a class `IPhone` that holds the attributes `series`, `color`, `memory` and `price`. Creating several sheets is not a real problem, you only have to coordinate what to write to what sheet. Try creating a blank workbook with 3 sheets and write it, I think you might get an idea about it then... (you already create a sheet in your code, you can do that several times).

Comment: i want store only phone name and price.....plz help me i dont want to create manually.

Comment: Are these `String`s in your question all the phones you want to write? Or are there more?

Comment: i want to store in one sheet all apple iphone xs,another sheet i want to store all apple iphone 8plus  like this

Comment: There are two *Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)* in your dataset, but they have different prices... Is that desired?

Comment: yes it desired...if there is 10 apple iphone xs then i store 10 aplle iphone xs with their different different price in one sheet

Comment: So basically, you want one sheet per first `String` for each array, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one sheet for each unique name you have in your list of arrays...
The following code rearranges the entries you provided into a `Map<String, List<String>>` in order to have the unique phone name as key and all the prices (unique or not, your decision) in a list as value. Have a look at the code comments:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String[]> data1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        data1.add(new String[] { "Apple iPhone 8 Plus (Space Grey, 64 GB)", "56000" });
        data1.add(new String[] { "Apple iPhone 6 (Grey, 128 GB)", "47000" });
        data1.add(new String[] { "Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)", "28000" });
        data1.add(new String[] { "Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)", "29000" });
        data1.add(new String[] { "Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Gold, 128 GB)", "19000" });
        data1.add(new String[] { "Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Gold, 128 GB)", "18000" });

        Map<String, List<String>> pricesPerPhoneName = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        /*
         * rearrange the given data in order to have unique names as keys and then use
         * those for sheet creation
         */
        data1.forEach(arr -> {
            String phoneName = arr[0];
            String price = arr[1];
            // check if the key is present in the map
            if (pricesPerPhoneName.containsKey(phoneName)) {
                /*
                 * add another price to the list of prices for the current key, check if the
                 * price is already contained and do nothing if yes...
                 */
                List<String> prices = pricesPerPhoneName.get(phoneName);
                if (!prices.contains(price)) {
                    prices.add(price);
                }
            } else {
                // put key and a list with the (one and only so far) price
                List<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
                prices.add(price);
                pricesPerPhoneName.put(phoneName, prices);
            }
        });

        /*
         * Now, you have all the prices stored as values of each key, which is a unique
         * phone name. The remaining code handles the creation of elements of the workbook
         */

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        // provide a full path to the workbook
        Path workbookPath = Paths.get("C:\\iphones.xlsx");  // CHANGE TO YOUR PATH

        // creat a sheet for each phone name and write the data into it
        pricesPerPhoneName.forEach((name, prices) -> {
            /*
             * ########################################################################
             * ### please note that names for sheets in excel have a limited length ###
             * ### that's why the common prefix gets replaced by nothing here       ###
             * ########################################################################
             */
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(name.replace("Apple iPhone", ""));

            // write one row for each price
            for (int i = 0; i < prices.size(); i++) {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
                // write the phone name in column A and the price in column B
                XSSFCell phoneNameCell = row.createCell(0);
                XSSFCell phonePriceCell = row.createCell(1);
                phoneNameCell.setCellValue(name);
                phonePriceCell.setCellValue(prices.get(i));
            }

            // make the columns fit their content
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
        });

        // write the workbook via FileOutputStream
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(workbookPath.toAbsolutePath().toString())) {
            // write the workbook using the FileOutputStream
            workbook.write(fos);
            // force the FileOutputStream to write everything until it is empty
            fos.flush();
            // close the FileOutputStream
            fos.close();
            // close the workbook.
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

There are possibilities of formatting the cells, like telling Excel to use some monetary formatting for the price cells, but that is up to you ... and basically another question ;-)